# JQuery Show Hidden Div command inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery function:

```
function MyFunction() {
     //I need a command here to show a hidden div
     ....
}


<div id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none"></div>
```

Basically, I need to Div above to show when the function is called.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with using `$('#hiddenDiv').show()`?

```
function MyFunction() {
     $('#hiddenDiv').show();
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options.

```
<div id='hiddenDiv' style='display:none;'></div>
```

then...

```
MyFunction('hiddenDiv');

function MyFunction(divId) {
     //$('#' + divId).show();
     $('#' + divId).fadeIn('fast');
     //$('#' + divId).slideDown('fast');
}
```